# How to delete a commit as if it was never created (but all the following commits still happened)?

Tags: git

I made a commit that was incomplete, so I want to delete it and add those changes to a new commit I'm creating right now. The problem is, there are multiple other commits between then and now that I want to keep, so `reset` won't work.

How do I remove this small commit as if I never made it, but everything else after it still remains?

Comment: There's no commit that's too small to be worth being a commit. Generally, preserving history is the most important bit; thus, to "undo" a commit, you make an inverse commit with `git revert xxxxxxx` (which will be of roughly the same size as the original commit you're reverting).

Comment: @Amadan I'm aware of that. I'm certain that I want to delete it.

Comment: What you want is `git rebase -i`, not `git revert`. Change the commit after it to `squash` instead of `pick`. I agree that history rewriting is dangerous, and if you `push`ed it anywhere it is more complicated and *just not worth rewriting history*, but it can be useful if the history is so far only private.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, but `drop`, not `squash`. `squash` will meld it to the adjacent commit; `drop` will make it as if it was never made.

Comment: @Amadan My impression is that the OP wants the trees of all the later commits to be the same, and just wants it to be as though they skipped running `git commit`, not skipped making those changes.

Comment: @DanielH correct, I want to put those changes in a new commit that I'm making right now (not merge them with another previous commit). And it is a solo repository, so no worries about rewriting history - I wouldn't do this on remote where others may have already pulled.

Comment: Note that you can also just reorder the lines inside the interactive rebase, bring the commit you want to the bottom (without changing anything else - no `drop` and no `squash`), and that will effectively "move" the commit to the end of your history, just like you want it. Of course, if you get conflicts... gods help ye :P

Comment: @Amadan That's a more succinct way to get the result I wanted. Phrasing it this way also yielded more relevant search results, thanks for the idea :)